# Why does this recursive method keeps calling itself even though the call is inside if statement?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on a problem where I design a method which counts the occurences of x in a string recursively. As you can see from the output below the code when i == 6 the if conditional which also contains the recursive call is not excecuted any further. However why is "countKeep is 4" printed multiple times?
Further, when I uncomment the line count = 0; i only receive "countKeep is 4" one time while the following lines print "countKeep is 0" and 0 is returned.

As I understand it the variable countKeep should be set to the variable count. Then the variables count and i are set to 0 for following strings. countKeep is then returned and gives the occurences of x in this string.

What am I missing with this beginner problem?

I call the method by:

```
    System.out.println(p.countX("xxhixx"));

    int count;
    int countKeep;
    int i;

    public int countX(String str) {
      if (i < str.length()) {
          System.out.println("i in outer if is " +i);
            if (str.charAt(i) == 'x') {
              count++;
              System.out.println("count in inner if is " + count);
            }
          i++;
          System.out.println("i is " +i);
          countX(str);
      }
      countKeep = count;
      System.out.println("countKeep is " + countKeep);
//    count = 0;
//    i = 0;
      return countKeep;
    }
```

**Output:**

```
i in outer if is 0
count in inner if is 1
i is 1
i in outer if is 1
count in inner if is 2
i is 2
i in outer if is 2
i is 3
i in outer if is 3
i is 4
i in outer if is 4
count in inner if is 3
i is 5
i in outer if is 5
count in inner if is 4
i is 6
countKeep is 4
countKeep is 4
countKeep is 4
countKeep is 4
countKeep is 4
countKeep is 4
countKeep is 4
4
```

Comment: is does not continue calling itself, it just bubbles the callstack back up. The last output of each call is the print of countKeep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you reach the setting of the countKeep and the printing of it, you call the method countX() again. So it will only reach this code (the code after your if-statement) after it has completed all the calls you did on countX(). Therefore it's also called 6 times.

The following code would show better what is actually happening:

```
System.out.println(p.countX("xxhixx"));

int count;
int countKeep;
int i;

public int countX(String str) {
  if (i < str.length()) {
      System.out.println("i in outer if is " +i);
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'x') {
          count++;
          System.out.println("count in inner if is " + count);
        }
      i++;
      System.out.println("i is " +i);
      countKeep = count;
      System.out.println("countKeep is " + countKeep);
      countX(str);
  }
  System.out.println("Finished the countX() method");
  return countKeep;
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve the problem but do not quite understand. Why is  System.out.println("countKeep is " + countKeep); called even though it is outside the if statement?

Comment: You said : "So it will only reach this code (the code after your if-statement) after it has completed all the calls you did on countX()." Doesn't this imply that System.out.println("countKeep is " + countKeep); is called after the recursive calls have finished?

Comment: The recursive calls aren't finished yet, they just start nesting deeper. Only once your 6th call is done, it will start returning countKeep and printing the line outside of your if statement, and actually finishing all the 6 methods that you called one by one, in the reverse order that you called them. So think of it like a pile (or stack), every time you reach the statement countX(str), you stop with your current item, put a new item on the top, and work with this, until you're either finished with it (then you remove it from the pile), or you put a new item on top of it.

Comment: Wow great explanation I would not have figured this out myself. It makes sense now. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Recursive functions are quite hard to wrap your mind around, surely in the beginning, but once you get the concept it will become easier!